# Relaciones en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Me podrían dar ideas para relacionar mi tabla de usuarios con empleados y clientes?. Estoy elaborando una base de datos de una institución donde tanto empleados como clientes puedan ingresar a un portal web, con sus respectivos permisos, y les quiero asignar usuario y contraseña ademas de asignarles tipos de usuarios.eh pensado en diferentes opciones pero no se cual sea la correcta

1. agregar a las respectivas tablas los atributos usuarios y contraseña
2. Borrar las dos tablas anteriores y englobarlas en una sola tabla que se llame usuario

el problema con estas opciones es que no sabría como relacionarlas con las tablas

pd: ignoren la relación que tiene actualmente. es una prueba que estaba realizando

Espero me puedan apoyar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta pregunta parece muy basada en opiniones. Y en general para diseñar una db se necesita muchas mas información que la que proporcionas. Un cliente es definitivamente distinto a un empleado. Ahora para acceder, como distinguiria el portal un cliente de un empleado? recorreria las 2 tablas fijandose en cual existe? es posible, sobre todo si tenes una vista. O si tenes una tabla usuarios tambien funciona. O sea, salvo que estes teniendo un problema concreto, los dos modelos parecen funcionar.

Comment: este tema es muy amplio pero en escencia teniendo la tabla Usuario y como campos usuario, clave, nombre, tipo_usuario...este diseño es muy cerrado donde existiria un usuario por cada tipo que desees es decir una persona debera tener mas de un usuario.....

Comment: bien para esto en la misma tabla Usuario podrias tener  campos como usuario, clave, cliente, empleado, etc.... donde cliente  y empleado sean tipo integer y con esto son los permisos al momento de consultar el usuario traes y validas que niveles tiene y muestras las opciones disponibles para el mismo, con esto una persona tiene un usuario con diferentes permisos.

Comment: Podrías crear dos tablas una TipoUsuarioRel y TiposUsuario donde en tipos de usuario podrías tener N cantidad de tipos de usuario como cliente, empleado etc y en TipoUsuarioRel relacionas al usuario con su tipo

Answer (score 3):

no existen estándares para la creación de un login, puedes complicar mucho o simplificarlo,  para esto deberías hacerte varias preguntas, por ejemplo:

1. La mas básica, Todo empleado es un usuario, y todo cliente es un usuario? si es así, entonces usuario es otra entidad.
2. Si estamos de acuerdo en que un cliente es una persona y un empleado es una persona, entonces persona es otra entidad, y para esto hay dos enfoques:

   - La entidad persona tendrá propiedades tanto del cliente como del empleado; o
   - Crear dos entidades una para clientes y otra para empleado y cada una relacionarlos 
     con la entidad persona.
3. Haz pensado en que cuando se habla de "Tipos de Usuario" te estas refiriendo a Roles, y que cuando hablas de "Permisos", estas hablando de Accesos a "ciertas áreas" (que son Aplicaciones en tu sistema) en concreto de tu aplicativo?, si es así, entonces se deben crear tres entidades mas: Roles, Permisos y Aplicaciones.
4. Haz pensado o sabes si por ejemplo quisieras saber que empleado atiende a que usuario?
   si es así? deberás averiguar sobre relaciones recursivas para poder poner en una misma tabla una propiedad o columna donde puedas poner la pk de la misma tabla que le corresponde a la fk.

En principio es muy importante que tu escenario este muy claro y que tu levantamiento de requerimientos llega este tipo de glanuralidad para que tengas claro cual es la Entidad - Relación que quieres Desarrollar.

Espero haberte podido guiar.